# What's the DRM Model Ubisoft is Using for Assassins Creed III on the PC?

Tags: assassins-creed-3, drm

I'm trying to see if the *rumors* about Ubisoft coming to their senses about super-intrusive DRM apply to their AAA titles. So far Google has two completely conflicting articles about DRM for Assassins Creed III dated back in September.

Now that the game is out on PC, I was wondering if anyone knew if they had actually moved back to a sane model.

Comment: They're still using Uplay... so not much has changed in that front.

Comment: Steam has no DRM listed on AC3's info page.  Considering Ubisoft got burned last time when they didn't say they included it with From Dust I'd be surprised if they included it again.

Comment: @zero298: I asked mainly because I don't trust them after From Dust. I see a couple threads complaining about UPlay on the steam forums but nothing definitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses Uplay (yes, even on the Steam version), which needs to be kept running in the background.

I did some testing:

- Offline mode is available. You need to have logged in to Uplay on the computer you're using at least once before.
- You won't get kicked out if the game if you get disconnected from the internet.

Comment: Is this still the case on the **Steam** Edition? Will I need to run thier U(dont)Play service when I'm connected to steam? What about offline play? I can I play single player if I'm disconnected from the internet?

Comment: I'll give offline play a go when I get home - but yes, it still uses Uplay on the Steam edition, and yes, you need to keep Uplay running in the background.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I have completely disconnected internet from my PC in playing using a dvd/uplay combination. You have to use uPlay at least once, but from observation it appears not to really respect the "offline mode" or cloud sync (there's messages inside the game and uPlay pop ups which indicate it's still running?).

Mainly did this to stop blue screens, which were happening between 5-30min intervals (and losing saves along the way). Played a solid 4 hours on higher quality settings than initially tested during blue screens, but disconnected seemed to do the trick for me.

So no "always on" DRM it seems - might at least be the opposite for me :)