# Can I install the game on multiple machines or resell the game?

Tags: pc, drm, assassins-creed-4-black-flag

- Can it be installed on multiple machines?
- Can I sell it after I am done with the game (just a like a console disk)?

The best information I found around this the following link which talks about DRM; [What's the DRM Model Ubisoft is Using for Assassins Creed III on the PC?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94479/whats-the-drm-model-ubisoft-is-using-for-assassins-creed-iii-on-the-pc).

Thanks

Comment: http://www.kotaku.com.au/2013/10/the-goodbad-of-assassins-creed-ivs-odd-online-singleplayer-features/

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Single-Player-Contents-Locked-Behind-Paywall/forum/FxV1VN5FN8W89I/Tx3RB5RPSCPQWBI/1/ref=cm_cd_dp_tp_cq?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B00BMFIXZG&cdSort=oldest#Mx3T0RFZFYYVQPL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PC games most often uses a CD-key that once it's used it's not up for grabs again like on a console.

Consoles solve this matter by having a requirement to have the disk inside the console to start the game.

On PC you can pretty much install then throw away the CD.

Reguarding AC4 i think you have to bind it to a Ubisoft account.

**Q1:**
So yes, you can install it on as many computers as Ubisoft / steam / Origin allows.

**Q2:**
But you can't sell your copy of the game after you have "activated"/"Used" your cd-key

Comment: Thanks! I would opt for steam in that case, installation media is backed up.

Comment: You can sell the account though, if you make a seperate UPlay Account for the game.